# mysql get one field from one table into another page list type

Tags: php, mysql

i am new in php, i have one table has `customer_name` how to get this **customer name** in my page as a combo box.

then i click submit only store the id only

please query and code for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

---

example code, hope it helps

```
<?php 
$db_name = "db";
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "SELECT customer_name,id from customers ORDER BY customer_name desc";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$db) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>=1){
    $form = '<form method="POST" action="">
    <p>Customer name:<select size="1" name="customer">';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $form .='<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.ucwords($row['customer_name']).'</option>';
    }
    $form .=' </select></p><p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p></form>';
}
echo $form;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would select the `id` and `name`.

```
SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `customer_name`
```

You would then echo a `select`, placing the `value` attribute as `id` and the text node as `name`.

This will transmit the `id` on form submit.

Answer (score 0):

to show select box from db is like this

```
<select name="categoryID">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT customer_id, customer_name FROM customers ".
"ORDER BY customer_name";

$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
  echo "<option value=\"".$row['customer_id']."\">".$row['customer_name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

read [more](http://www.tech-evangelist.com/2007/11/22/php-select-box/)

Comment: You don't close your `option` elements?

Comment: Both the customer name and identifier could contain HTML -- it would be prudent to use `htmlspecialchars` here as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you.

```
<?php

    // make connection with database
    $db_name = "test";
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection) or die(mysql_error());

    $sql = "SELECT customer_id, customer_name FROM customer_name";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    // start process of making combo box
    $comboBox = "<select name='cust_name'>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      // add option with list
      $comboBox .= "<option value='". $row['customer_id'] ."'>". $row['customer_name'] ."</option>";
    }

    $comboBox .= "</select>";

    // echo this comboBox variable where you what to display this comboBox. like this
    echo $comboBox;

    //  when you put this combo box within form you can get vlaue of this comboBox like this

        // $_POST['cust_name']; // this return customer id of selected customer

?>
```

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone-  You can see there are too many changes in my and your code.. lol